# Is synthetic division ever useful outside of a low-level algebra course?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am an economist, so I use various kinds of mathematics. My daughter is learning synthetic division in high school algebra. I have never come across it in my 30 years in economics. Does it have a use in higher mathematics? Is it worth teaching in high school?

Comment: This belongs more on matheducators than here. That being said, to echo a commonly expressed sentiment here, the purpose of teaching algorithms like synthetic division is that they teach the process of learning a procedural methodology and applying it in a new setting, a skillset which is immensely valuable. And I do use synthetic division when I'm in a crunch, although calculators have certainly obviated the necessity of the procedure.

Comment: I just want to add that while synthetic division (the particular algorithm) might not have much application in higher mathematics, the fact that one can divide polynomials with remainder is very useful in many fields.

Comment: For a practical example, polynomial division is the first step in [partial fractions decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Over_the_reals), where the link lists several real life applications.

Comment: If the synthetic division is being taught in such a way that your daughter actually understands *why it works*, it sounds like a great exercise.

Comment: Thanks, especially dxiv for the link, but that doesn't really answer my question. Don Thousand is closer. One can contrive some possible uses. I'm wondering if, in doing "real" math, for some purpose other than as an example, people actually use this method.

Comment: ANY math is good for the mind, but each topic chosen is pushing out some other topic. My daughter has not yet heard of  open vs. closed intervals with the (), [] notation, for example. A little real analysis seems  to me more useful than synthetic division, and easier-- but that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: @EricRasmusen Not sure what you call "real" math, but polynomial rings, Grobner basis and Laplace transforms are both theoretical and applied math staples, and they all make use of polynomial division in some shape or form.

Comment: Eric, from what I have seen on this site, the best thing you can do for your child  is get some graph paper   and show how to draw simple things (before calculus)  as $y = x + \frac{1}{x}$  and such. I quite liked the "college algebra"  textbook I taught from once, can't recall authors. The second thing is vectors, at least in dimensions 2 and 3, perhaps cross product. I tried to tutor a kid who was starting linear algebra, without that initial few weeks of basic pictures/calculations it was hopeless, and the parents let her drop the class....

Comment: anyway, the graph paper is the big thing.  It is disheartening to have a student here respond to me "but I can;t draw the graph, they don't let us use graphing calculators."  A child who can graph anyway is in a better position, later calculus actually makes sense

Comment: probably Lial and Miller

Comment: dxiv, those would count as real math. I don't mean "fancy", but "used outside the classroom", so both multiplication and Laplace transforms count, for example.

Answer (score -1):

well, a concrete task with polynomial division and remainder, it finds the gcd(over the rationals) of two polynomials, then constructs the Bezout relation (in integers $ax +by = \gcd(a,b)$ )

In this case, one of the polynomials is the derivative of the other, there is a nontrivial common factor, so the  square of that factor divides the first...  the second step uses continued fractions, it turned out one may use continued fractions with polynomials.

$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 4 x^{2}  - 3 x  + 18 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  3 x^{2}  - 8 x  - 3 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 4 x^{2}  - 3 x  + 18 \right)  =  \left(  3 x^{2}  - 8 x  - 3 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 3 x  - 4 }{ 9 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{  - 50 x  + 150 }{ 9 }  \right)  $$
$$  \left(  3 x^{2}  - 8 x  - 3 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{  - 50 x  + 150 }{ 9 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 27 x  - 9 }{ 50 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$
$$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 3 x  - 4 }{ 9 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 3 x  - 4 }{ 9 }  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 27 x  - 9 }{ 50 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  - 9 x^{2}  + 9 x  + 54 }{ 50 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  - 27 x  - 9 }{ 50 }  \right) } $$
$$  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  - 6 \right)  \left( \frac{ 9}{50 } \right)  -  \left(  3 x  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 3 x  - 4 }{ 50 }  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$
$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 4 x^{2}  - 3 x  + 18 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  - 6 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 3 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$  \left(  3 x^{2}  - 8 x  - 3 \right)  =  \left(  3 x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 3 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 3 \right) }   $$
$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 4 x^{2}  - 3 x  + 18 \right)  \left( \frac{ 9}{50 } \right)  -  \left(  3 x^{2}  - 8 x  - 3 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 3 x  - 4 }{ 50 }  \right)  =  \left(   -  x  + 3 \right)  $$